# increase serial no when click toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck with increase serial no automatically,When I click Add button,It is add new field,But the serial no should be increasing can you guys help me..

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="sno[]" class="form-control" placeholder="S. No." value="1"/>
</div>
<span class='toggler date'>
    <a class="btn btn-condensed btn-sm">
        <div style="font-size:16px"> 
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</span>
<span class='toggler date' style='display:none;'>
    <a class="btn btn-condensed btn-sm">
        <div style="font-size:16px"> 
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</span>
```

And When I click add button this html will append

```
<div class='toggled_content1' style="padding-bottom:15px"></div>
<div class='toggled_content' style='display:none;'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12"> 
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="sno[]" class="form-control" placeholder="S. No."/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And toggle javascript,

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.toggler').on('click',function(){
        var fff=$(".toggled_content").html();
        $(".toggled_content1").append(fff); 
    });
});
```

Can you guys help me when i click add button,how to increase S. No. Automaticlaly.

Comment: Where do you want to use the incremented S. no? Do you want to use it as the placeholder of newly generated input?

Comment: When I click Add button the text box value should be 2,and Next one 3 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a counter for getting next S. no. One approach can be to get the number of `.form-group` elements already inserted and add 1 to it to get the next S. no.

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.toggler').on('click',function(){
      var newSNum = $(".toggled_content1 .form-group").length + 1;
        var fff = $(".toggled_content").html();
        $(".toggled_content1").append(fff); 
        $(".toggled_content1 .form-group").eq( newSNum - 1 ).find("input").val( newSNum );
    });
});
```

```css
.input-group
{
  clear: both;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.toggler
{
  border: thin solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="sno[]" class="form-control" placeholder="S. No." value="1"/>
</div>


<span class='toggler date'>
    <a class="btn btn-condensed btn-sm">
        <div style="font-size:16px"> 
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</span>
<span class='toggler date' style='display:none;'>
    <a class="btn btn-condensed btn-sm">
        <div style="font-size:16px"> 
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</span>

<div class='toggled_content1' style="padding-bottom:15px"></div>


<div class='toggled_content' style='display:none;'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12"> 
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="sno[]" class="form-control" placeholder="S. No."/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
$(function () {

  $('.toggler').on('click', function () {

    var fff = $(".toggled_content").html();

    if (!isNaN(fff)) {

        console.log(parseInt(fff,10) + 1);
        $(".toggled_content1").html(parseInt(fff, 10) + 1);
    }
 });

});
```